# Firebase Login with twitter Not working in React native

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, twitter, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use twitter in Frebase authentication on a react native app. I am using the following code to do it

```
      const { RNTwitterSignIn } = NativeModules;

      RNTwitterSignIn.init(TwitterKeys.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, TwitterKeys.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)

          RNTwitterSignIn.logIn()
            .then(loginData => {
              console.log("loginData="+loginData.authToken + " "+ loginData.authTokenSecret)
              console.log(JSON.stringify(loginData));
              const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(loginData.authToken, loginData.authTokenSecret)

              return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);

            }).then((currentUser)=>{
              this.props.navigation.navigate('FlyerListing')

              //--------------------------Async Test--------------------------
                AsyncStorage.setItem("user", currentUser.uid)
                console.log("AsyncStorage= "+ currentUser.uid)
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
            })
```

and when I try to login it I got following  error in console :-

> {code: "auth/invalid-credential", message: "Unable to parse Google
>   id_token: 150550928-ZJgBitL44wrST6DKCWhUx9b2dmNo10RGyQZ"}

How can I fix this.

> Note :-I am using the same method for login with google and its
>   working fine

Comment: Login with twitter is already active in firebase

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Iwas using const

> credential =
>   firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(loginData.authToken,
>   loginData.authTokenSecret)

insted of

> const credential =
>   firebase.auth.TwitterAuthProvider.credential(loginData.authToken,
>   loginData.authTokenSecret)